# helm-occur: how to make it behave more like isearch?

Tags: helm, isearch

I switched to `helm-occur` for searching within buffers. However, I can't help missing two of the nice features of `isearch`:

1. `isearch` remembers the position where it was invoked in a buffer; `helm-occur` doesn't: when typing a search query, the focus is on the first match of the buffer overall, not on the first match after the cursor position in the buffer.
2. When typing `C-s` within `isearch`, at first the last search query is reactivated, and then, upon further uses of `C-s`, it cycles through all the matches in a buffer. On the contrary, with `helm-occur`, I have to first reactivate the last search query with `M-p`, and then do the browsing with some third key binding, e.g. `<down>`.

How can I make `helm-occur` act just like `isearch` in these two respects?

Comment: As you can see, it's called "helm-occur", not "helm-isearch". `helm-occur` is an "interactive" (I mean you can view results as you type) version of `M-x occur`, so it always searches the whole buffer.

Comment: Maybe you can give "swiper" a try, it might do what you want. Simply type `C-h P swiper` to learn about it.

Comment: @xuchunyang So you are sure that one cannot change this? Thanks for hinting at `swiper`. I'm already playing around with `helm-swoop` which seems to resolve the two issues for me.

Comment: I don't think that's not possible, but it should be easier and better to simply pick up another tool.

Comment: You can use `helm-resume` to bring up the `helm-occur` window at the occurrence you previously selected; this allows you to go to the next occurrence.

Comment: I second trying out `swiper`. I found `swiper` to be a wee bit more responsive and fast than `helm-swoop`