# helm-swoop: how to make it behave more like isearch?

Tags: helm, search

Following up on a recent question of mine ([here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28542/helm-occur-how-to-make-it-behave-more-like-isearch)), I would like `helm-swoop` to behave in a certain way when pressing `C-s` that parallels the behaviour of `isearch`:

1. `C-s` in a buffer: open `helm-swoop` with empty search field.
2. `C-s` in `helm-swoop` with **empty** search field: activate previous search.
3. `C-s` in `helm-swoop` with **non-empty** search field: go to next match.

The tricky parts are 2. and 3. obviously. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
;; C-s in a buffer: open helm-swoop with empty search field
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'helm-swoop)
(with-eval-after-load 'helm-swoop
    (setq helm-swoop-pre-input-function
        (lambda () nil)))

;; C-s in helm-swoop with empty search field: activate previous search.
;; C-s in helm-swoop with non-empty search field: go to next match.
(with-eval-after-load 'helm-swoop
    (define-key helm-swoop-map (kbd "C-s") 'tl/helm-swoop-C-s))

(defun tl/helm-swoop-C-s ()
    (interactive)
    (if (boundp 'helm-swoop-pattern)
            (if (equal helm-swoop-pattern "")
                    (previous-history-element 1)
                (helm-next-line))
    (helm-next-line)
    ))
```